# React Meteor: parent data in child component's container

Tags: meteor, reactjs, meteor-react

I'm following the official meteor guide 1.3 and how to integrate react. The guide doesn't thoroughly explain the usage of container pattern. My question is how to pass parent component data to child component's container so that I can write subs with parent's _id parameter? Or am I wrong with this pattern? Should I just write one big publications that publishes all child components' data too? In blaze you have Template.parent.data() function. I'm new to React so excuse me.

Comment: See updated react-meteor-data package doc [here](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/react-meteor-data)